# showOptionDialog buttons on separate lines

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, joptionpane

can't get the buttons in the OptionDialog to appear on a new line.
They all appear in one row, but I'd like to have them on separate lines.

I also tried setting up a frame to add to the OptionDialog (to set the max width), but it didn't work out for me either.

Any ideas/help/suggestions appreciated.

```
Object[] options = { "Button1", "Button2", "Button3", "Button4", 
     "Button5 On a newLine\n\n", "Button 6", "Button 7" };
int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose a button..", "Title",
     JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
     null, options, options[0]);
```

Comment: `JOptionPane` is a great component for when you can use it as-is.  But if too much customization is required, it is usually easier to roll-your-own dialog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this alternative.

[image: combo box options]

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Options {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Object[] options = {
                    "Option 1",
                    "Option 2",
                    "Option 3",
                    "Option 4",
                    "Option 5",
                    "Option 6",
                    "Option 7",
                    "None of the above" 
                };
                JComboBox optionList = new JComboBox(options);
                optionList.setSelectedIndex(7);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, optionList, "Title",
                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using the Option Dialog from JOptionPane, but you still can create your own dialog window by extending [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), and this way you will be able to use the layout you want for your components.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own OptionPane class if you want to break buttons in multiple lines.

You'll be breaking a bunch of UI standards in doing so, though.

Answer (score 1):

The same kind of answer as above, but more concrete:

```
 Object[] options = outputcdirs;
    JComboBox optionList = new JComboBox(outputcdirs);
      optionList.setSelectedIndex(0);
      JPanel jpan = new JPanel ();
      jpan.add(new JLabel("Select dirs:"));
      jpan.add(optionList);
      int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, jpan, "text...",
                                     JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                     null,
                                     null,
                                     null);
      if (n != -1)
        n = optionList.getSelectedIndex();
       if (n == -1)
            throw new Exception("No selection: ...");
        String value = outputcdirs[n];
```

Comment: This is the best example so far as it properly handles cancel conditions.